# Chrome Browser not closing current tab using Javascript window.close

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

We have an ASP.Net MVC application where we show static SessionExpired html page after session timeout. The SessionExpired page is shown using window.location from another page. We have a close window button in SessionExpired page which has a javascript click function **window.close()** to close the window. However this is not working in chrome browser.

I have tried all the solutions from the net but they are not working in chrome version v78.

I tried to open SessionExpired page by using **window.open** instead of **window.location** as below

```
window.open("SessionExpired.html","_self")
```

As I should not open a new tab. But not able to close the window using the below solution

```
window.open('','_self').close();
```

The above solution works if I use

```
window.open("sessionExpired.html");
```

But as I mentioned I cannot open a new tab and keep the existing tab open.

Answer (score 1):

If I'm understanding you correctly, you're saying that:

1. The user opens a tab and starts using your application.
2. At some point the user stops using the application and it sits idle.
3. The user's session expires and so the page refreshes with an expiration message and a Close button that does `window.close()`.
4. Clicking the Close button doesn't close the page.

If so, I'm afraid you're not going to be able to make that Close button work. You can't close windows that the *user* opened programmatically.

You might instead have a button that takes them to the sign-in page of the application (within the same window).

Comment: Hi Crowder, Thanks for quick response.So is this Chrome browser security reason we cannot close the window. It seems some of the solutions in the net worked fine in earlier versions of Chrome but not in V78. It seems chrome will only close windows which are opened using window.open with no extra params like _self etc.

Comment: @RavindraReddy - I don't think this is new, `window.close` not being able to close a window the *user* opened is pretty fundamental. I just tested it in Chrome v49 and it didn't work.